# Android - GoogleApiClient instance lost between .connect() and onConnected() in IntentService

Tags: android, location, intentservice, google-api-client

I'm trying to manage starting and stopping location updates (and other connected operations) from an IntentService triggered by changes to the enabled state of the GPS. The problem comes because the .connect() method on the GoogleApiClient runs asynchronously, which allows the service to die. By the time the callback is received for onConnected(), the static global variable mGoogleApiClient has been wiped. For removeLocationUpdates() I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: GoogleApiClient must not be null
```

and for requestLocationUpdates() I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

What is the right way to retain the instance of the GoogleApiClient (which is a required parameter for both request and remove methods) between the death and rebirth of the IntentService? Or if that's the wrong question, what is the right way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT (19APR15) :
Here are the relevant sections of code...

From my class that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver that listens for GPS events:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // If user enables or disables GPS
    if(intent.getAction().equals(LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION) || intent.getAction().equals(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, ActivationIntentService.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("enabled", isGPSEnabled(context));
        startWakefulService(context, mIntent);
    }
}
```

From ActivationIntentService class that receives the intent passed from startWakefulService:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null) {
        this.intent = intent;
        if(intent.hasExtra("enabled")) {
            if(intent.getBooleanExtra("enabled", false)) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
            }
            else {
                stopUpdates();
            }
        }
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    return mLocationRequest;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    startLocationUpdates();
    startActivityRecognitionUpdates();
    ActivationReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

public void stopUpdates() {
    PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, new Intent(this, LocationIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,locationPendingIntent);
    PendingIntent activityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, new Intent(this, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.removeActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,activityRecognitionPendingIntent);
}

public void startLocationUpdates() {
    PendingIntent locationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, new Intent(this, LocationIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, getLocationRequest(), locationPendingIntent);
}

public void startActivityRecognitionUpdates() {
    PendingIntent activityRecognitionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 2, new Intent(this, ActivityRecognitionIntentService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 5000, activityRecognitionPendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?  I just completed a project using the Google Play Services Fused Location API.  One key is that before calling `requestLocationUpdates()` and `removeLocationUpdates()` I did a check that the `GoogleApiClient` is not null, and is connected.

Comment: I will add in the pertinent parts of the code so you can see it.. However, at this stage, it would be pointless to check whether the client is null. In this current setup, it will always be null, so I don't need to check for it.

Answer (score 2):

My first suspicion was correct. I was trying to solve the wrong problem.

After detailed debugging by tracing almost every method call, I realized that the system was broadcasting the GPS mode change twice for some reason, so that a second GoogleApiClient had been instantiated (overwriting the first instance) by the time the first onConnected callback was fired from the first .connect() call. The second (not connected) client variable was being used instead of the first for my methods to start or stop updates, which caused the exception to be thrown. Since the system fires two broadcasts EVERY time the user either enables or disables the GPS (seems kind of stupid to me), I set a flag in the BroadcastReceiver so that I can ignore the second one. Problem Solved.

Comment: I have found a better way since then. The only reason to connect the client asynchronously is to prevent blocking the UI thread. However, I was not performing this task on the UI thread in the first place, so there is no reason to worry about that. To make things simpler, I switched to the synchronous method called blockingConnect(), which I didn't even know existed initially. Method description here : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#blockingConnect%28%29